# Looking for info on ninerays.win.widgets.dll

Tags: c#

I've inherited a C# program that makes extensive use of widgets from ninerays.win.widgets.dll. The solution builds fine and even runs under mono in a Armbian Linux environment.

However I have to make modifications to this program and I have no documentation regarding this DLL. I wonder if anything is out there. Also when I attempt to open some of the panels in Designer I'm seeing this error:
[image]

I wonder if part of the problem is the NineRays dll file.

I would appreciate any documentation on this dll file and any suggestion on opening panels in designer.

Comment: Your error does not seem to match the title of your question?  What is the link between your error and the dll you mention?  Have you looked at the website www.9rays.net (not sure if this is the right site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not sponsored!

get dotpeek and let it create some documentation for you :)

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Excellent, didn't know about this. Dead useful.